# setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility changing custom title bar view width

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, loading, titlebar

When using ActionBarSherlock(ABS) setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true|false) the custom title view width is changed, which is probably caused by the fact that ABS sets the indeterminate visibility to gone instead of invisibile.

I see too solutions, that I'm still working in:

- set a custom indeterminate bar that belongs to the customView, but the visual effect wouldn't be so nice;
- having a way to mess with ABS code that doesn't set the bar visibility to gone...

Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I predicted, ABS changes the visibility to gone.

Ii've chosen the second option, which is a quite simple solution.
I downloaded the ABS code, imported it and changed the class ActionBarSherlockCompat

Where is View.INVISIBLE was View.GONE before.

Method:

```
public class ActionBarSherlockCompat .... {
   private void updateProgressBars(int value) {

   ...
   else if (value == Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_OFF) {
            if ((features & (1 << Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS)) != 0) {
                horizontalProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if ((features & (1 << Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)) != 0) {
                circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
   ...
   }
}
```